# PHP: How to count values from database and create a top 10 leaderboard of counted

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

How would I create a way to count and display a leaderboard of such where it's organized by the number of times values occur? 
example database:

```
Bob
Joe
Bob
Bob
Joe
Sandra
```

And then the table would be

```
Bob - 3
Joe - 2
Sandra - 1
```

I am unsure how this is done. Thanks!

Comment: Do you use MySQL? You are looking for a basic SQL query with `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`. Look for a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query for something like this is:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS CounterNames
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY Name
 ORDER BY CounterNames DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Because you need the name and you want to count the names also, you're selecting these, but you dont want that the name is double in the db, so you are using `GROUP BY`.
The ORDER BY colum_name DESC is that you are ordering after the Counter and have the biggest value first (DESC).
LIMIT because you only want the top 10.

Comment: so when displaying the data how would this go? I have this so far `$result = $conn->query("SELECT Name, COUNT(Name) AS CounterNames
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY Name
 ORDER BY CounterNames DESC
 LIMIT 10");
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $Top = $row['CounterNames'];
   

    }
  }
echo $Top;

}`
but this only echos back out 1. I think my query is wrong when it comes to the displaying of it

Comment: How many entries do you have?    And you only give your variable `$top` the value of how many times the name is counted.

Comment: the entries would be like the example database above. But how would i make it so it displays like i have above using the query you provided?

Comment: `echo $row['Name']."-".$row['CounterNames'];`